# How can I create a Laravel Resource relationship for a belongsTo?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-resource

I have created a `UserResource` that is successfully returning all of my user attributes, including the organization it belongs to. It looks something like this:

**Resources/User.php**

```
return [
    'type' => 'users',
    'id' => (string)$this->id,
    'attributes' => [
        'name' => $this->name,
        'email' => $this->email,
        ...
        'relationships' => [
            'organization' => $this->organization,
        ],
    ];
```

In my `User` model, there is a `belongsTo` relationship for `User->Organization`.

Instead of returning the actual organization model, I'd like to return the organization resource.

For example, an organization `hasMany` locations:

**Resources/Organization.php**

```
return [
    'type' => 'organizations',
    'id' => (string)$this->id,
    'attributes' => [
        'name' => $this->name,
        ...   
        'relationships' => [
            'locations' => Location::collection($this->locations),
        ],
    ];
```

I can successfully return the collection of locations that belong to the organization. I have not been able to return a `belongsTo` relationship.

I've tried:

**Resources/User.php**

```
'relationships' => [
    'organization' => Organization::collection($this->organization),
],

// or this
'relationships' => [
    'organization' => Organization::class($this->organization),
],

// or this
use App\Http\Resources\Organization as OrganizationResource;
...

'relationships' => [
    'organization' => OrganizationResource($this->organization),
],
```

How can I return a single model as a related resource? Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried it with the `new` keyword?

```
'relationships' => [
    'organization' => new OrganizationResource($this->organization),
],
```

Comment: That was it - thank you!
Out of my own naïveté, why do I need to use `new` for returning a `belongsTo`, but can simply just use the `::collection` to return a `hasMany`?